# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'

Tags: python, парсер

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

result = requests.get("https://cabinet-auction.gosreestr.kz/p/ru/auction-v2")

result.status_code
result.headers

c = result.content

samples = soup.find_all('div')
samples[0]
```

Пытаюсь сделать парсер, но постоянно выдает одну и ту же ошибку. 
Возможно ошибка из за того что в этот сайт на авторизоваться, но надеюсь что я делаю что-то не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так а в чём вы ищете? Вы же результат реквеста никак не используете. Должно быть так примерно:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # убрал отсюда soup

...
soup = BeautifulSoup(result.content)
samples = soup.find_all('div')
samples[0]
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, сам не заметил что написал